# How can force library to check targetSdkVersion of main app in compile time

Tags: android, sdk, dependencies, lib, targetsdkversion

I have some library in [github](https://github.com/mahdit83) that want to be more user friendly. For being more user friendly i want to check compatibility with my lib and main-app in compile-time.

This is how problem came:
I have updated my lib for android **Oreo** and if user set **targetSdkVersion** to **27** it will be fine. Problem is when user set his app target to 27 but use my old lib version. This cause crash in my lib.

For checking compatibility of main app, i have to check **targetSdkVersion** of main app from my library. Is that possible? or is there any other way to force lib-user-app to meet my dependencies not just by documents?

Comment: I thought you need NOT to do so, Android make compatible with prev versions. No matter which targetSdkVersion your lib will works. only concern about `MinSdkVersion`

Comment: @xingjiu No. recently I had many problem with android 8.0. So if user use old version of lib and put their targetSdkVersion to 27 my lib crashes. this is the problem. But it is ok with my last version

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should care about `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` in your lib instead of `targetSdkVersion` in the main app. After all, the app crashed because of `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` does not match new Android feature.